# ThreadPool thread doing I/O operation - can thread be reused while waiting?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, threadpool

I have been reading a bit about async/await vs ThreadPool vs Threads, and I have to admit, I'm not fully clear on the details. There is one specific question that I *think* I have the answer to, but I can't say for sure.

I am also aware of the many many questions on SO and elsewhere, where these questiosn are being discussed and explained. I have read a fair few here on SO, but I haven't found a clear answer, or at least as clear as I'd like.

What I gathered:

- Using async/await in an I/O operation, will make that thread available to use for other things, while the I/O operation continues elsewhere
- For a server application, this means higher throughput etc

However, a collegue said something like this:

- that using a ThreadPool to execute the same I/O operation would behave almost the same as async/await
- that when the ThreadPool thread "hands over" the I/O operation to the OS, it might wait for the answer, but that it won't matter much, since there is no work done on the CPU (the thread is waiting), and thus, the ThreadPool/OS/framework can use or spawn another thread to do some other work.
- Since the threadpool has a limit of some 32000+ threads, it wouldn't matter much, since it could just use more threads. The cost for a thread is very small, just a few bytes of memory

So, what I am asking is:

- Does the Thread from a ThreadPool block in I/O operations?
- Does it matter if it does, since the OS/framework/Threadpool can just use another thread from the pool if needed for some other work?
- Bottom line: I/O operations with async/await or ThreadPool; does it matter for efficiency and throughput?

Please note that I am not discussing the client-side of things, just from a server perspective.

And sorry in advance if I missed an exact answer to this, I have looked =)

Comment: "The cost for a thread is very small, just a few bytes of memory" - No, it's over 1MB. Each thread has its own stack that is 1MB in size.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for that update. However, that cannot be the only gain, to avoid the 1MB memory usage?

Comment: Your answers are "Yes", "NA/No/No", "Depends on what you mean by efficiency and throughput".

Comment: What do you mean by "that cannot be the only gain"? What gain?

Comment: The point is to try to find out if a ThreadPool doing I/O work has the same througput/efficiency as async/await construct, as described. My collegues claims are above, so he says it doens't matter, as the ThreadPool will just use another thread for new work, so its close to irrelevant in a choice between the two.

Comment: Why not test it out yourself? The only way to know which horse is faster is to race the horses. Asking us which horse we **think** is faster is not helping anyone.

Comment: Your colleague apparently has a limited understanding of how asynchronous I/O on Windows actually works, or else you misinterpreted the remarks. With true asynchronous I/O (`async`/`await`, `.Begin...`/`.End...`) there *is* no waiting thread, there are only pending operations and threads that get pressed into service as necessary. This is a huge difference from doing synchronous I/O with threads that actually sleep and wait for a result, which is inefficient no matter if you use thread pool threads or your own. "Just add more threads" is precisely what does *not* scale.

Comment: See also Stephen Cleary's "[There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)", which explains this in more detail.

Comment: @Enigmativity If you're not interested in answering, then please dont. Smart-ass comments are not relevant or interesting.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for that input. Right, I am aware that after the async/await model has handed over the "work" to the OS (in case of an I/O operation for example), there is no thread waiting. My collegue is also aware, but his point is that it doesnt matter if the Threadpool thread waits, since it is not doing any work anyways, so no load on the CPU and no problem since threadpool can have 32000 threads, and unless you are going up to those numbers, "no harm done". Im just trying to clarify how it works and where the added value with async/Await is =)

Comment: Blocking code is the enemy of the ThreadPool. Pushing long-running, blocking jobs onto the ThreadPool will cause your app to become unresponsive in surprising ways. The ThreadPool is ***reluctant*** to spin up new threads in reponse to a spike in queue length. This means that work queued to the ThreadPool might, under load, take some time to be dequeued and executed. The assumption here is that work in the ThreadPool is meant to be short-lived. Blocking IO is not short lived, and you'll hit performance issues faster than you think. Timer callbacks, for instance, run in the ThreadPool.

Comment: @Ted - It wasn't a smart-ass answer. I was offering a practical suggestion. No matter what you hear here, you won't know how variations of your own particular code will fair unless you measure them. I'm just trying to save you time and effort - you're going to have to measure eventually.

Comment: Your colleague is wrong. Yes, a waiting thread expends no CPU itself, but 1) creating threads is a an expensive operation, 2) each thread consumes 1 MB of memory, as already indicated, and 3) context switching between a potentially unlimited number of threads is expensive (as opposed to the handful used for I/O queues). You can try 32K async operations at a time, or 32K threads at a time, and *see* which is better-- you'll find that trying to create 32K threads that wait will probably bring the system to its knees before your test can even finish. TL;DR: bookkeeping overhead matters.

Comment: A thread per IO has long since been shown to be a bad idea when doing heavy-lift IO. If you're dealing with a trivial example, it doesn't really matter... but server software? Don't do it.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am not asking for measurements on our code specifically. I am asking a specific question with a general answer. I am not asking anyone to asses our code or to benchmark it at all. So, it wasnt answering the questions nor was it helpful.

Comment: @Ted - "I am aware that after the async/await model has handed over the "work" to the OS" - No, it doesn't. `async`/`await` is purely a framework construct. It has nothing to do with the OS. Ultimately, though, all I/O eventually, by definition, gets sent to the OS. The two are 100% independent of each other.

Comment: You should ask what your colleague has in mind when they're talking about "thread pool threads". Do they mean queueing an I/O operation to the thread pool "old style" (using the `.Begin...`/`.End...` APIs) or do they mean using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` with a function using synchronous I/O? The former scales as well as `async`/`await` (as both use asynchronous I/O under the hood), the latter does not (as it adds an extra layer of synchronous waiting).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Agreed, if we reach 32k threads, its bad. But lets say a less extreme example, say, 100 requests or I/O operations. And in this case, he means using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - It sounds like there are a few options. Do you think that the OP might need to try implementing a few and then **measure then to see which is best**? (Yes, Ted, I think this is starting to border on smart-assery. LOL)

Comment: If you know you will never have more than 100 operations "in flight", and you pre-create those 100 threads, then it's likely the overhead is not (as) noticeable (although that extra 100 MB should still be visible). But that first one is a big "if" -- the major appeal of `async`/`await` is that it allows you to write async code as if it was sync, while *still* getting the benefits of scaling for free. There is no real incentive to give this up by just posting synchronous code to the thread pool -- *especially* for server code, which you really want to be scalable.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Alright, feel free to add an answer here where you say sort of the same thing as above and anything else you might have to add, so I can award the answer =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real issue is not "thread pool vs. `async`/`await`", it's synchronous I/O vs. asynchronous I/O. [1]

On Windows, threads are relatively expensive objects -- a thread has a lot of OS bookkeeping associated with it, not to mention 1 MB of preallocated stack space. This puts a fairly low cap on how many threads the system will even support, and even when you don't hit that cap, context switching between all those threads is not cheap either. That "32,000 threads" limit is a strictly theoretical one, and highly optimistic about how many threads you can have and still be responsive! [2]

Enter asynchronous I/O, which is optimized to use only as many threads as necessary (usually some conservative multiple of the number of physical processor cores in the system), ideally never even creating new threads beyond the initial batch. These threads are dedicated to handling completed I/O operations by removing them from a queue (known as a completion port). While an asynchronous operation is in progress, no thread is dedicated to it at all, not even as an item on a wait list (Stephen Cleary has a nice [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) about it that explains this in more detail). Not much imagination is needed to think about what's more efficient:

- A few thousand individual threads that each wait on a particular operation, which have to be woken up and switched to (and between) depending on what operation(s) completed; or
- A few dozen threads (if that), each of which can handle any completed operation, so that only as many ever need to run as necessary to be responsive.

As it turns out, the latter scales much better than the former; the "thread per request" model which is common in naive server code quickly shows its limits, even when you use a thread pool to reduce the creation of new threads. Note that this was an issue long before `async`/`await` was ever a thing, and so is the solution Windows went with; `async`/`await` is just a new way of writing code to use the existing mechanisms.

Are you likely to notice a difference with only a few requests in flight at a time? No. But since `async`/`await` essentially allows you to write code that looks synchronous but has the scalability of asynchronous I/O "for free", why would you *not* choose to use that in favor of synchronous I/O queued to the thread pool?

---

[1] Turns out Stephen Cleary already [wrote most of what's in this answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) a few years ago. I recommend you read that as well.

[2] Here's an [older post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/) by Mark Russinovich where he actually tries to squeeze as many threads out of the system as possible -- just for fun and profit. He "only" gets to 55K on a 64-bit machine before all resources are gone, and that's with adjusting the default stack size, and without doing any actually useful work. On a modern system you could probably get more, but the real question should not be "how many threads can I have" -- if it is, you're Doing it Wrong.

Comment: "The real issue is not "thread pool vs. async/await"" - exactly. Like I said in my [async ASP.NET article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx), asynchrony allows your app to make maximum use of the thread pool. It's not an "either/or" discussion; it's "both/and".

Comment: @StephenCleary: thanks -- yoinked and put in the answer, in case the comment gets lost.