# CPU benchmark test: Tasks vs ThreadPool vs Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

I posted [another SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425062/threadpool-thread-doing-i-o-operation-can-thread-be-reused-while-waiting), and as a follow-up, my colleague did a test, seen below, as some form of "counter" to the argument for async/await/Tasks.

(I am aware that the `lock` on resultList isn't needed, disregard that)

- I am aware that async/await and Tasks is *not* made to handle CPU-intensive tasks but instead handle I/O operations that are done by the OS. The benchmark below is a CPU-intensive task, so the test is flawed from start.
- However, as I understand it, using `new Task().Start()` will schedule the operation on the ThreadPool and execute the test code on different threads on the ThreadPool. Wouldnt that mean that the first and second test are more or less the same? (I'm guessing not, please explain
- Why then the big difference between them?

[image]

Comment: I would guess that 1M `Task` objects in first example is an issue. And the difference between 2nd vs 3rd example, that 2nd has 1M closure objects, so garbage collection would be far more intense.

Comment: That's kind of comparing Apples and Oranges. Try restricting to 10 Tasks with loops and 10 UserWorkItems with loops or create 1M Threads, then it is slightly comparable. You can code anything so that it will fail some performance test if you do want so.

Comment: This test doesn't make sense, and your colleague hasn't proved anything apart from **how to make a weird tests that shows nothing**. However, all that aside, the *Async and Await pattern* isn't about speed or performance its a *IO scalability feature*, and lets you write *conitunations* seamlessly with *Synchronization contexts*, though on saying this there is no *Async Await pattern* shown in any of these tests. I think both you and your colleague need to spend more time reading and less time trying to prove each other wrong.

Comment: @TheGeneral I have read and I am trying to explain wht it is to him. Unfortuantely, I have so far been unable to get through, at this point.

Comment: Probably a good place to start is Stephen Cleary, and Stephen Toub, both have a wealth of information or the Async and Await pattern, parallelism, task, threading, and the thread pool. they all have their places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> some form of "counter" to the argument for async/await/Tasks.

The posted code has absolutely nothing to do with `async` or `await`. It's comparing three different kinds of parallelism:

1. Dynamic Task Parallelism.
2. Direct threadpool access.
3. Manual multithreading with manual partitioning.

The first two are somewhat comparable. Of course, direct threadpool access will be faster than Dynamic Task Parallelism. But what these tests don't show is that direct threadpool access is much harder to do correctly. In particular, when you are running real-world code and need to handle *exceptions* and *return values*, you have to add in boilerplate code and object instances to the direct threadpool access code that slows it down.

The third one is not comparable at all. It just uses 10 manual threads. Again, this example ignores the additional complexity necessary in real-world code; specifically, the need to handle exceptions and return values. It also assumes a partition size, which is problematic; real-world code does not have that luxury. If you're managing your own set of threads, then you have to decide things like how quickly you should increase the number of threads when the queue has many items, and how quickly you should end threads when the queue is empty. These are all difficult questions that add lots of code to the #3 test before you're really comparing the *same thing*.

And that's not even to say anything about the cost of maintenance. In my experience (i.e., as an application developer), micro-optimizations are just not worth it. Even if you took the "worst" (#1) approach, you're losing about 7 *microseconds* per item. That is an unimaginably small amount of savings. As a general rule, developer time is far more valuable to your company than user time. If your users have to process a *hundred thousand* items, the difference would barely be perceptible. If you were to adopt the "best" (#3) approach, the code would be much less maintainable, particularly considering the boilerplate and thread management code necessary in production code and not shown here. Going with #3 would probably cost your company far more in terms of developer time *just writing or reading the code* than it would ever save in terms of user time.

Oh, and the funniest part of all this is that with all these different kinds of parallelism compared, they didn't even include the one that is *most suitable* for this test: PLINQ.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskParallelLibrary();
    ManualThreads();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ManualThreads()
{
    var queue = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i != 1000000; ++i)
        queue.Add("string" + i);
    var resultList = new List<string>();
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var t = "";
                lock (queue)
                {
                    if (counter >= queue.Count)
                        break;
                    t = queue[counter];
                    ++counter;
                }
                t = t.Substring(0, 5);
                string t2 = t.Substring(0, 2) + t;
                lock (resultList)
                    resultList.Add(t2);
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    while (resultList.Count < queue.Count)
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Manual threads: Processed {resultList.Count} in {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
}

static void TaskParallelLibrary()
{
    var queue = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i != 1000000; ++i)
        queue.Add("string" + i);
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var resultList = queue.AsParallel().Select(t =>
    {
        t = t.Substring(0, 5);
        return t.Substring(0, 2) + t;
    }).ToList();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Parallel: Processed {resultList.Count} in {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
}
```

On my machine, after running this code several times, I find that the PLINQ code outperforms the Manual Threads by about 30%. Sample output on .NET Core 3.0 preview5-27626-15, built for Release, run standalone:

```
Parallel: Processed 1000000 in 00:00:00.3629408
Manual threads: Processed 1000000 in 00:00:00.5119985
```

And, of course, the PLINQ code is:

- Shorter
- More maintainable
- More robust (handles exceptions and return types)
- Less awkward (no need to poll for completion)
- More portable (partitions based on number of processors)
- More flexible (automatically adjusts the thread pool as necessary based on amount of work)